# Return closest attribute from radio button with JQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons, I want to use JS / JQuery to extract the data-product-name from whichever is clicked (before any form submission).

I am trying this sort of code but can't get it working:

```
    return jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest("form").attr('[data-product-name]');
```

For context, this is to use in Google Tag Manager custom JavaScript variable to put the data in some tracking.

Radio button code:

```
    <div class="choose-variants">
    <input type="radio"
    id="MB0"
    name="variantSku"
    value="MB"
    data-unit-price="9"
    data-product-name="HB MB" checked />
<label for="MB0">B &amp; C
<span>Save<strong class="choose-label">Recommended</strong></span>
</label>
<input type="radio"
    id="MB-O1"
    name="variantSku"
    value="MB-O"
    data-unit-price="9"data-product-name="HB MB O"/>
<label for="MB-O1">B only
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example for you. Click on the radio buttons and you will get your output in console:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('product-name'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choose-variants">
  <input type="radio" id="MB0" name="variantSku" value="MB" data-unit-price="9" data-product-name="HB MB" checked />
  <label for="MB0">B &amp; C
<span>Save<strong class="choose-label">Recommended</strong></span>
</label>
  <input type="radio" id="MB-O1" name="variantSku" value="MB-O" data-unit-price="9" data-product-name="HB MB O" />
  <label for="MB-O1">B only
</label>
```